# How to disable "recent files" folder in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

When I turn off " record activity" in the privacy settings, my activities are still recorded in the "recent files" folder (even when I am using a truecrypt volume).

I haven't figured out a PERMANENT solution to this problem. It sucks to delete history via terminal manually and what happens if I forget?

Comment: One of you should post that as an answer, but beware that does not clear everything (such as bash history and specific applications may also track recent files).

Comment: Exactly how are you deleting the history via the terminal? I'd really like a temporary solution.

Comment: in Ubuntu 13.04 the settings.ini file is in /etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini and the configuration will be applied for all users

Answer (score 50):

The method with editing `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` doesn't work with Nautilus 3.8.
But there is better and simpler way.
Simply open `dconf-editor`, navigate to `org->gnome->desktop->privacy` and uncheck the `remember-recent-files` key. That takes care of it, once for all!

Comment: `org->gnome->desktop` doesn't have `privacy` for me in 13.04.

Comment: +1 neat. For noobs like me, `dconf-editor` just runs in my terminal - it's a UI :)

Comment: in Gnome 3.8 Settings -> Privacy -> Turn of Usage & History

Answer (score 16):

Using the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.privacy remember-recent-files false
```

Answer (score 9):

### Disable the Nautilus Recent Files list

To permanently disable any recent files from showing up in the Nautilus Recent sidebar item, open the `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` file with a text editor:

```
gedit ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

and under "[Settings]", add the following lines:

```
gtk-recent-files-max-age=0
gtk-recent-files-limit=0
```

If this file does not exist, create it. Make sure the header says "[Settings]" and not "Settings". This is how the file should look after editing it:

```
[Settings]
gtk-recent-files-max-age=0
gtk-recent-files-limit=0
```

(there can be other items below these, of course).

To apply the changes, log out and log back in.

<sub>Copied from [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/) exercising (cc) BY-NC-SA WebUpd8 : [Nautilus 3.6: How To Clear The Recent Files List (Or Disable It)](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/nautilus-36-how-to-clear-recent-files.html)</sub>

Comment: Doesn't work for me on 13.04.

Answer (score 8):

In 14.04 go to Settings > Security & Privacy > Files & Applications and check "off" [image: Record file and application usage].

Comment: not work! i excluded all the  videos, my movies folder, my video player applications.. but it keep adding videos into "Recent" list

Comment: It worked at the time for me in 14; I've been using 16 for awhile now and couldn't say if its still valid or not.

Answer (score 7):

#### If you're using Ubuntu 17.10 and above (or Ubuntu GNOME) then:

- Open Settings
- Open the Privacy Tab
  [image]
- Click *Usage & History* and disable the "Recently Used" label
  [image]

Comment: the only answer that worked.kudos

Answer (score 3):

Starting with GTK 3.8 (Ubuntu 13.10 and later) you can just use the following setting in
`~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` to disable the "Recent files" feature completely:

```
[Settings]
gtk-recent-files-enabled = 0
```

Comment: didn't work for me on 13.10, dconf-editor solution works well

Comment: Maybe worth doing the same for ~/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini config file!

Answer (score 2):

You have 4 options (AFIK)

1. Use the guest account. The guest account is confined by apparmor and the session is wiped when you log out.
2. Each user should have a separate account.
3. Write a script to clear your private data.
4. use bleachbit.

Comment: I suppose you could always boot from a flash drive as well.

Answer (score 1):

As the `settings.ini` method didn't work for me on Ubuntu 13.04, here is a workaround that should be pretty reliable:

```
$ rm ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel # clear current file history
$ touch ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel # create a 0-byte history file
$ sudo chattr +i ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel # make it readonly
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply open `dconf-editor`, navigate to **org**->**gnome**->*(filemanager e.g. nemo for me)*->**privacy** and uncheck the **remember-recent-files** key. That takes care of it, once for all!

Answer (score 0):

### gnome 42

in gnome 42 one can set the recent-files-max-age to `0`.

> Recently used files will be remembered for this many days. If set to 0, recent files will not be remembered; if set to -1, they will be retained indefinitely.

[image: dConf Editor /org/gnome/desktop/privacy/recent-files-max-age]