# Why doesn't removing "recently-used.xbel" clear my "Recent" folder?

Tags: nautilus, zeitgeist

I have searched on Google, and I have completed the following steps:

- Delete "all" activity history from the "Privacy" application.
- Remove the file "recently-used.xbel" from `~/.local/share`
- `$ nautilus -q`
- Remove the file "activity.sqlite" from `~/.local/share/zeitgeist`
- `$ zeitgeist-daemon --replace &`

I checked my "Recent" folder in between all of the above steps and none of them had any impact. I also tried:

- Remove all files with "sqlite" in the name from `~/.local/share/zeitgeist` (3 files:)

  - activity.sqlite
  - activity.sqlite-shm
  - activity.sqlite-wal
- `$ zeitgeist-daemon --replace &`

None of the above had any impact on the contents of the "Recent" folder.

According to everything I've found, removing the file "recently-used.xbel" and restarting Nautilus should clear the "Recent" folder. Why isn't it working?

Comment: Guess what? You haven't Googled well enough. It's a duplicate of this question. - [How to disable “recent files” folder in Nautilus?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/294901/how-to-disable-recent-files-folder-in-nautilus)

Comment: @jokerdino: How to permanently disable recent folders? But that's not what I asked...

Comment: As far as I can tell this is a perfectly valid question, it shows research effort, it's clearly worded and could well be useful for other people. Why the down votes?

Comment: My apologies for hastily closing. So, you don't want to disable but just simply clear it whenever you wish? It seems like clearing it is not perfect. See [Nautilus 3.6: How To Clear The Recent Files List (Or Disable It)](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/nautilus-36-how-to-clear-recent-files.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why removing `recently-used.xbel` isn't working. But if you want to do it the clicky way:

1. Select all files in *Recent*
2. Right-click on the selected files
3. Click on *Remove from Recent*

[image]

* on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Nautilus didn't work, logging out and back in (oddly) didn't work, but restarting the computer did the trick. I'm curious to find out whether this was just a fluke or if I have to reboot every time I want to clear the "Recent" folder.

Comment: you can also just open Recent, highlight all the files & from the r. click  context menu  remove them. (my current nautilus has a remove option, if not there then just choose delete instead

Answer (score 1):

You can. Just open the recent folder, select all by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and clear by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>?

Answer (score 0):

Simply open `dconf-editor`, navigate to `org->gnome->(filemanager e.g. nemo(for me)->privacy` and uncheck the `remember-recent-files` key. That takes care of it, once for all!

Btw I'm using Peppermint 8, it works for me in the File Manager, while for startup menu, you can just open start menu (whisker menu for me) and in `Behavior` tab input `0` for Amount of items under `Recently Used`