# Nautilus history

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

I want to know does nautilus maintain any Navigation History file of visited folders.

- If yes then where it is storing its history ?
- If not then is it possible to monitor the nautilus either using 
  script or using any packages and create a history file ?

Comment: For more info check out this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34592/how-to-clear-recently-used-files-without-using-a-terminal

Comment: also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/318129/why-doesnt-removing-recently-used-xbel-clear-my-recent-folder?lq=1

Comment: Both link only provides answer of "How to delete recent history?". But i want to access history list.

Answer (score 5):

The nautilus itself doesn't keep logging history, but you can find history of what you have done in the file `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`

From here you can just invoke a script or search by hand for what you want.

Hope this could help

Comment: `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` only store a file name when it has been used. Suppose I am going to `~/Picture` folder and coming back to `~/` , then it is not going to store  `~/Picture` in it's list.

Comment: Yes that's right for that I stated in my answer that it doesn't keep a logging history. this is just a workaround that can benefit you a little